# Is extracting formatted input from std::cin with a single line of code possible?

Tags: c++, stream

Say I have a function `compute_number(float k);` and in my program, I need to call this function once with some user input as the argument. The intuitive way to achieve formatted input, would be:

```
int main()
{
...
float input_numbr;
std::cin >> input_numbr;
compute_number(input_numbr); 
...
}
```

The problem with this, though, is that I've declared and used an extra variable `float input_numbr` which I'll never use again. I think that's a waste.

So my question is if there's any way to reduce these three lines into one. There must be some way to circumvent the need of creating an additional variable to get one-time formatted keyboard input from an input stream. I'm thinking of something like:

```
compute_number(cin.get());
```

The problem with that, however, is that cin.get() does not format the input; it simply returns the ASCII value of whichever character happens to be next in the stream.

So is there a way to call `compute_number(cin.next_formatted_input())` like so? Or must one create an additional variable for temporarily holding the formatted cin value.

Comment: The result has to be stored _somewhere_. What you're suggesting would need to perform a temporary allocation regardless before passing the result to `compute_number`, so you wouldn't be saving anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem with this, though, is that I've declared and used an extra variable float input_numbr which I'll never use again. I think that's a waste.

Well, I disagree (advocating for code readability), but here you go:

```
 template<typename T>
 T getinput(std::istream& is) {
     T result;
     is >> result;
     return result;
 }
```

should do what you want. You can just write

```
 compute_number(getinput<float>(std::cin));
```

then. Though a variable is still involved (and needed).

Comment: That indeed does what I want. I'll definitely have to read up more on templating because it looks like some really powerful stuff, thanks.

Comment: @DavisHerring I can't see any UB here? Reference please?

Comment: Hm.  It _was_ undefined behavior once, but since C++11 it stores zero on error.  Never mind!